# How do I replace the '|' character in a string in java?

Tags: java, string

I have a weird problem in one of my programs, I simply want to replace every occurrence of "||" with "OR" in a string, but for some reason it replaces every blank space with "OR", is "|" some sort of escape character or something?

I've been using this statement to do it

```
ans = ans.replaceAll("||", "OR");
```

Does anyone know what's going on or how I can fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`replaceAll` uses regex syntax and in regex `|` is operator representing `OR` operation which means that `"||"` is interpreted as regex as:

`""` OR `""` OR `""` - empty string OR empty String OR empty String

If you want to change `|` into literal you need to escape it for instance by adding `\` before it (in string `\` needs to be written as `"\\"`).

But to avoid this confusion you can use `replace` instead of `replaceAll` which will do escaping part for you.

So instead of

```
ans = ans.replaceAll("||", "OR");
```

simply use

```
ans = ans.replace("||", "OR");
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `replace` which doesnt use regex in its first argument

```
ans = ans.replace("||", "OR");
```

Answer (score 1):

`replaceAll` function uses regex to match characters. Since `|` is a special character in regex , you need to escape `|` symbol in the regex to match a literal `|` symbol.

```
ans = ans.replaceAll("\\|", "OR");
```

This will replace every `|` symbol with `OR`.

For two pipe symbols.

```
ans = ans.replaceAll("\\|\\|", "OR");
```

This will replace every two pipe symbols `||` with `OR`